# LINQ build tree from a collection of deeply child menu ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Im using **EF Core** and have an entity of `Menu` like this:

```
public class Menu : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Menu Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And also a bridge entity for each `User` to their authorized menus (many-to-many):

```
public class UserMenu
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
}
```

For this case, I will only save **leaf node** of menu mapping in the `UserMenu` table. For example, I have a list of menu data like this:

```
MenuId ParentId    
1      NULL   
2      NULL   
3      1   
4      1   
5      1   
6      1   
7      2   
8      7
```

And menu mapping for a `User` with `id = 1` like this:

```
Id UserId MenuId    
1  1      3   // (leaf node only)
2  1      4   // (leaf node only)
3  1      5   // (leaf node only)
4  1      6   // (leaf node only)
```

And now I need to generate the `MenuViewModel` for the `User` as a tree structure:

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

For the above example, it should produces a tree like this:

```
[
  {
    MenuId: 1,
    Children: [
      {
         MenuId: 3,
         Children: []
      },
      {
         MenuId: 4,
         Children: []
      },
      {
         MenuId: 5,
         Children: []
      },
      {
         MenuId: 6,
         Children: []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any ideas for this **upwards** traverse case if I only save the **leaf node** for the `User-Menu` bridge?

Comment: could you show us the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: @sam My idea is to loop through the list of menu belongs to that `User` and for each menu and their ancestors, I put them into the `Dictionary<int menuId, Menu menu>` as flatten. After that, I cast them into `List<Menu> outList`, and then converting them into a hierarchy by using LINQ: `outList.Include(m => m.Children).AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.Parent == null).ToList()`;